# Basic VB NET - Make a button on form 1 do the same as button on form 2?

Tags: vb.net, button

Here's the code I got:

### On FormNew:

```
Public Class FormNew
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 
            Dim writer As New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName) 
            writer.Write(TextBox1.Text) 
            writer.Close() 
        End If 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

### On Form1:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click 
        FormNew.Button1.Click() 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

The line that does not work is `FormNew.Button1.click`. How do I fix this? I just want to press the button on form 1 and want it to think I'm pushing the button on FormNew. That way I can save the text that I type on FormNew when I click "Save" on Form1, instead of clicking the save button on formNew.

Comment: "Private" means private.  How would the user know that selecting a menu option on Form2 will save the contents of a TextBox on Form1? What if the other form is not showing at the time - or worse, isnt instanced?

Comment: Its a very small program, there is only a menu and Text box with save on it

Comment: Try: FormNew.Button1.PerformClick()

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
FormNew.Button1.Click()
```

with

```
FormNew.Button1.PerformClick()
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like the following by creating a function in the module

```
 public Sub Button1_Click()
 If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 
 Dim writer As New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName) 
 writer.Write(TextBox1.Text) 
 writer.Close() 
 End If 
 End Sub
```

then you can call the function from anywhere in the application.the call will be like the following

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click 
Button1_Click()
End Sub 
End Class
```

in formnew

```
Public Class FormNew
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
Button1_Click()
End Sub 
End Class
```